# Ship's Mage build (wind/water/weather themed caster)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, druid, e6

I'm looking for some help with a character build for an upcoming pirate-themed Pathfinder game, which will probably run using the 'Epic 6th' rules.

I'm looking for suggestions to help ensure that the character is at least moderately combat-functional, while staying within the guidelines of the theme.  The 1st level power of the Water domain will probably be the character's primary ranged attack, but suggestions are certainly welcome.

**1)** Is the build as it stands actually capable of standing its own in combat?  How could it be improved?  The build's AC is pretty abysmal at this point (10-14) depending on armor and final stat choices.

**2)** Would the tradeoff of taking a single level of Monk early (1st or 2nd level) be worth what I'd lose from the 6th level of Druid, or would it be better to go with the Heirloom Weapon trait, and if so what aquatic/ship themed weapon would you suggest?

**3)** If not Heirloom Weapon, which of the other traits (listed below) would be most helpful? (Or have I missed one that would be better suited for the theme?)

**4)** What is the best way to improve the abysmal AC I seem to be hitting.  (12 without armor, 14 with leather

**Note:** I'm completely willing to sacrifice the animal-oriented aspects of the druid (wild shape, wild empathy, etc.) for the build, since it's so far from the concept that it isn't even on the radar.

---

## The Theme

I'm thinking an air/water/weather themed caster who is an apprentice 'windfinder' (a ship's mage whose job it is to ensure/enhance/enable favorable wind/weather for the ship's journey).  So far, it looks like the Druid has the best spell list for this theme, so I'm looking at an Undine Druid (Undine Adept archetype) with the Water domain, taking the Hydrated Vitality racial trait (maybe the Deepsight as well).

### Attributes

For attributes, I'm strongly stressing Wisdom, but Dexterity will be necessary to ensure a practical AC, so: Str 8 or 10; Dex 15 or 13; Con 10; Int 12; Wis 18; Cha 10

### Feat Selection

Concept-wise, I'm thinking a monk-like tradition (the idea started mostly because none of the druid weapons seem to fit the theme), so I'm trying to keep the build at least moderately effective unarmed.

My current plan for feats is as follows (in order from 1st level): Improved Unarmed Strike, Weapon Finesse, Bleeding Attack or Domain Strike.  The focus here is to ensure basic competence should someone manage to close the distance.  (I'm debating about taking a level of Monk at 2nd level to better empower the concept, especially since an epic 6th campaign will mitigate the otherwise huge power mismatch later in the game.)

### Background Traits

These are the traits I've found that seem to fit with the theme.  I'm pretty set on Marid's Fury, but can't decide between Natural Born Sailor, or Storm-Touched, and Heirloom Weapon might be better than either to help the build in combat.

**Heirloom Weapon** - This would get around the weapon proficiency limitations of a druid, but nothing is particularly striking me.  (Recommendations could change that.)

**Marid’s Fury (Undine)** - hydraulic push spell-like ability can extinguish magical fires.

**Natural Born Sailor** (Skull & Shackles)

**Storm-Touched** - DR 1/- against creatures and attacks with the electricity type.

### Thematic Spell List

Snipped for brevity.

Comment: @doppelgreener My issue is that "I'm looking for suggestions..." is followed by a complete build that appears both combat functional and thematic, so I'm wondering which aspects of the build he wants help with. If it's just "Any suggestions to improve this?" that seems a bit broad.

Comment: @Miniman Mm, that sounds reasonable. Theo, what exactly are you after here? Verification it's combat viable? What kind of obstacles or problems are you facing?

Comment: Theo, check out our guidance on [refining build/optimisation questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/are-character-optimization-questions-on-topic) on the meta site.

Comment: There's only a few areas where I'm looking for help.  I'll try to break out the questions a bit more clearly.  Looking at the link SevenSidedDie posted, I'd say this is a 'type 1'.  I have the concept and the basic build, but I'm not sure how effective it is and I'm looking for help optimizing it.

Comment: Any chance my edits are sufficient to get this opened back up?  If not, can I get some sort of indication *why*, and what fix(es) might?

Comment: So, does this mean my edits didn't help, or does it just mean that nobody actually *cares* whether the question gets clarified?  Seriously, asked one day, put on hold a few minutes later, edited the next day, and then radio silence from the folks who voted that it needed editing to be a good question.  Nothing for nearly a week, but it gets closed?  What's the point of demanding edits, if you're not going to come back and look at them later?

Comment: @Theo Hi! I've already voted to reopen. I am not sure about edits for improving it further.

Comment: @doppelgreener - Thanks. I can't see who has voted, and I can only '@' one person per post.

Comment: It's still broad and unclear. "Moderately combat-functional" doesn't have a precise meaning that answers can be measured against by voters, and the numbered list that follows which might have nailed that down just casts a really wide net instead.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - it's a heck of a lot more precise than any of the corresponding examples linked in the meta thread you pointed me to. Is there *actually* any way of posting character optimization questions other than 'build me a max DPS/AC/etc something or other' that isn't considered 'too vague'?  The meta thread lists three valid categories, and I've gone above and beyond the examples of two of them and gotten no feedback more helpful or informative than 'too broad/vague'. People ask charOp questions *because* they don't have all the answers.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman First, not all charop question fit *here*, even if people have them. With that out of the way, what I would suggest for sorting this out is to bring it to meta: pretty much say just what you've said in that comment, and ask the community what is up with that disparity in this specific case. That should get it wider attention for the question, and might even improve our meta guidance on charop questions.

Comment: (As for why I have not voted to reopen: as a mod now my vote is binding, so I don't cast it when a question is in a grey area of my expertise. I originally cast my close vote as a regular user and when this was much more unclear, so I could afford to cast it more loosely, knowing it would attract attention from others to vote yeah or nay. This is clear*er* now, but not enough for me to personally be 100% sure it's clear enough, especially when no other votes are on it. That puts me in an awkward position relative to this question now, so unfortunately I must punt.)

Comment: I find it moderately amusing that a question I asked almost 4 and a half years ago, which effectively only existed as a question for a few minutes, has just earned me the "Popular Question" badge.  I can only wonder whether any of those 1000+ views might have included answers.